# labelsync help required

Tags: perforce, synchronization, flush

Does labelsync actually sync a file from the depot?
or does it only require a file name?
If it does sync, then is there any alternate command like flush that wud work similar to labelsync but faster(i.e without syncing the files) ?
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labelsync modifies the set of files associated with a label, it does not sync a file from the depot. It is quite different from sync. There is a flush command: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/flush.html#1040665 Flush is similar to sync but it does not actually transfer the files.

I have no idea what sort of command you are trying to run, since flush and labelsync are used for two very different purposes, and both run very fast.

Perhaps you are looking for: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/01_intro.html#1067317

Comment: @ Bryan Pendleton---
i have been give a code to optimize...in that i had been told that lablesync actually syncs the file...but on reading about it i got to know that it doesnt..so i wanted to know what it does exactly...so lablesync is a real fast coommand na?

Comment: please confirm..i am completely new to perforce and perl

Comment: It's hard to say, in isolation, which commands are faster than others, because it depends on the arguments to the command, the structure and size of your repository, etc. To get a feel for what commands are more or less expensive, run your server with -Llog and -vtracke=1 arguments, then run your tool, then examine the server log and it will have recorded which commands it ran and how much resources they each took.